# tools for creating and checking android layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I spend an unpleasant time looking for erros in my android layout, fields not showing up being the predominant one. As I see other people here also struggling a lot with android layouts I thought to throw this question in even so not completely according to the SO question guidelines.

What tools are out there to help with the creation of android layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is only one i know. its called http://www.droiddraw.org/

over the time i figured though that the best is still to create your own by code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer SDK within Eclipse (eg android 4.0 or 4.1) it should help you with the layout (with much more functional drag and drop and alignment/spacing). However, you may still want to manually verify it to make sure it's exactly what you want, since you'll be changing other parameters too.

Comment: thx - I am using it yet often, particular when there is a problem with the layout, it doenst show the elements and so it is hard to find the problem -